# Crystal reports fonts

Tags: .net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

We have a win-forms application which uses crystal report 13 to show reports.
One of our  clients is running the application on windows xp and is having some trouble with the report. Weirdly the title of report is showing as blank rectangles but the body of the report is displaying proper text. I have checked that the font is installed the correct runtime for crystal engine is being run(13.0) and the correct .net 4 full version is installed.

Can any one please shed some light as to why this might be happening.

Thank you

Comment: Un-installing and re-installing the crystal runtime fixed the issue.

Comment: You should change your comment to an answer so this question can be marked as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un-installing and re-installing the crystal runtime fixed the issue